# Dependecy injection question (Python requests)

Tags: python, dependency-injection, software-design

I have a Python code for processing requests like this:

```
class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self):
    #somecodehere
    pass
  
  ...

  def some_method(self, db_data, input):
    #some code
    mixed_item = {**db_data, **input.get('specific_object')} #merge two information
    self.another_method(db_data, input)

  def another_method(info):
    #process info
    pass

obj = SomeClass()
obj.some_method(db_data, request_data)
```

Regarding dependecy injection, should I change **another_method** parameters so it receives *db_data* and *input* from **some_method** and leave the merging into *info* for **another_method** to handle?

Comment: Is `info` basically used as a dict of keyword arguments? Like `info['my-option']` `info['other-option']`?

Comment: Yes. What difference does it make?